# How to access data from inside the method findAll

Tags: node.js, express

I want to have the `Company` accessable in my dashboard.ejs. When I try to `res.render` from inside the `Company.findAll` I get an error `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`, when I render it outside it works properly but I can't acces the `data` aka the response from `Company.findAll` which I need in my EJS file to build the frontend.

Anyone might have an idea how to deal with this?

```js
router.get("/dashboard", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  User.update(
    {keyword_id: req.user['id']},
    {where: {id: req.user['id']}}
  )

  Company.findAll(
    {where: {userId: 2}}
    ).then(function(test) {
      test.forEach(data=>{
        res.render("dashboard", {user: req.user['dataValues'], data: data['dataValues']}); // THIS
      });
  });
  res.render("dashboard", {user: req.user['dataValues']}); // OR THIS
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code to below:

`User.update` is an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). You have to write the code which you want to execute in the callback of the async function.

```
router.get("/dashboard", isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    User.update(
        { keyword_id: req.user['id'] },
        { where: { id: req.user['id'] } }
    ).then(function (data) {
        Company.findAll(
            { where: { userId: 2 } }
        ).then(function (test) {
            // test.forEach(data => {
                // res.render("dashboard", { user: req.user['dataValues'], data: data['dataValues'] }); // -> This is wrong. Collect the data into an array and then send the response once
            // });
            res.render("dashboard", { user: req.user['dataValues'] }); // OR THIS
        });
    });
})
```

And also, for a given request, a response can be sent only once.

In the `Company.findAll` callback, you cannot have `res.render` multiple times. Collect the data into an array and then send the response once.

Comment: There's syntax error in the code example you've provided.

Comment: How may I use the test response with Company's data in the ejs file? That's what I want and the reason why I created this issue.